# Discrepancy in FileHandler in OneDrive Shared Library for office extensions

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive, filehandler

When a FileHandler is deployed. When we click on the filename in OneDrive Shared Library either all the office extension should open in microsoft application or all the office extension should open via FileHandler (If configured for those extensions)

Observed Behavior
I have created a FileHandler for the file type docx and xlsx. In OneDrive Shared Library when I click on a filename of type .docx, it is opened in Microsoft Word Online. However, when I click on a filename of type .xlsx, it is opened via the FileHandler.